# OR-Tools solve traveling salesman (TSP) without returning to the home node

Tags: python, optimization, traveling-salesman, or-tools

I'm using Google Or-Tools to solve a Traveling Salesman Problem by using [this](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp) example (basically I just replaced the distances matrix with mine). As in the example, I set `data['depot'] = 0`.

For my application it is not important to return to the first node at the end of the path. I can remove the last edge from the solution but I wonder that if I could remove this constraint altogether it might find a better path overall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the distance from all nodes to 0 (the depot) is null. This is equivalent to what you are asking for.

Comment: Wouldn't this skew the results? I do need to use this node as a starting point. What you're saying is that the first step will cost 0 no matter which is the next node. Also, wouldn't the optimizer would then try to get to the node just before the depot?

Comment: no. The step from any node to 0 will cost 0, not the step outgoing from 0. And you can only visit a node once, 0 included.

Comment: I understand but this would make the problem asymmetric and force me to use optimizers that support asymmetric costs. I will try anyway and come back with results.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this worked perfectly. Thanks!